# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extract'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to exclude a div and nav from a page. The first run seems to run great, but then it throws error.

From this page: https://www.velkesvatonovice.cz/windex.php/rubrika/elektronicka-uredni-deska/

"Exclude" code from: https://discuss.dizzycoding.com/exclude-unwanted-tag-on-beautifulsoup-python/

Im trying to get the text of an article (which is for example in the 5th article), but not the attachments (), and nav.

Console log:

> PS C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\py\velkesvatonovice.cz\scripts> python
> main.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>
> "main.py", line 53, in 
> unwantedAttachments.extract() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extract'

Problematic part of the code:

```
#Text full
        unwantedAttachments = artcontent.find('div', class_="attachments")
        unwantedAttachments.extract()
        unwantedNav = artcontent.find('nav')
        unwantedNav.extract()
        print(artcontent)
```

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from csv import writer

pageno=1
url= "https://www.velkesvatonovice.cz/windex.php/rubrika/elektronicka-uredni-deska/page/"+str(pageno)+"/"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
lists = soup.find_all("article")

#65

def normalize(str):
    return(re.sub(r'\xa0', ' ', str))

with open("listings.csv", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header= ["Name", "Text", "Text full" ,"Attachments" , "Category", "Category full", "Date", "URL", "Page"]
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for list in lists:
        categorieslist=list.find_all("a", rel="category tag")

        #Name
        article=list.find("a", rel="bookmark").text.strip()
        
        #Text
        text=list.find("div", class_="entry excerpt entry-summary").text

        #Category
        category = (categorieslist[len(categorieslist)-1])
        
        #Category full
        categories=""
        for cat in categorieslist:
            categories += (cat.text + "/") 

        #Date
        date=list.find("time").text
        
        #URL
        urlarticle=list.find("a", rel="bookmark")["href"]

        pageart = requests.get(urlarticle)
        soupart = BeautifulSoup(pageart.content, "html.parser")
        artcontent = soupart.find("div", class_="entry-inner")
        
        #Text full
        unwantedAttachments = artcontent.find('div', class_="attachments")
        unwantedAttachments.extract()
        unwantedNav = artcontent.find('nav')
        unwantedNav.extract()
        print(artcontent)

        #Attachments

        #Page

        item = [normalize(article), normalize(text), "ss", "Attachment", category.text, categories, date, urlarticle]
        thewriter.writerow(item)
```

Comment: `unwantedAttachments` is `None` and you're trying to `extract`.  What is this part supposed to do? I'm guessing your scraper hasn't found anything so it's yielding the error when extracting

Comment: It found a lot of stuff:
`<div class="attachments"><dl class="attachments attachments-medium">
<dt class="icon">
<a href="https://www.velkesvatonovice.cz/windex.php/2022/05/zapis-z-25-zasedani-zastupitelstva-obce-velke-svatonovice/?aid=13437&amp;sa=0" title="Zápis z 20220511_anonym">
<img alt="Zápis z 20220511_anonym" data-src="https://www.velkesvatonovice.cz/wp-content/plugins/eg-attachments/img/metro/document.png" height="38" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAA`

Comment: `unwantedAttachments` is `None` because it couldn't find any `div` with class `attachments`.

Comment: literally the first thing it outputs IS the div class attachments

Comment: In first iteration it's ok, but in the next it couldn't find anything. If you print `list` in each iteration, you'll see

Comment: Oh yes, youre right. A simple "if" fixed it. Thx

        `if unwantedAttachments:
            unwantedAttachments.extract()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple "if" fixes the whole problem. Thx @Ahmad for pointing it out.

```
#Text full
        unwantedAttachments = artcontent.find('div', class_="attachments")
        if unwantedAttachments:
            unwantedAttachments.extract()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to get you to do!